# group all receiver-id along with count and messages for each individual along with history msgs

Tags: mysql, sql, messaging

I have built a private messaging system and would like to group all id's like this : [image]

With names(ids) and count of messages ,and after click on the user it will open into history of all message history between them .And the new message when arrives will bring the user on top with count increasing along with new message and chat history .How do I do that ?

I have shared this http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/7b13a/1 .But I am unable to get the code or the procedure to arrive at it.
I really appreciate any help.Thanks in Advance.

Code:

```
CREATE TABLE if not exists tblA
(
id int(11) NOT NULL auto_increment ,
sender varchar(255),
receiver varchar(255),
 msg varchar(255),
 date timestamp,
 PRIMARY KEY (id)
);


INSERT INTO tblA (sender, receiver,msg,date ) VALUES
('1', '2', 'buzz ...','2011-08-21 14:11:09'),
('1', '2', 'test ...','2011-08-21 14:12:19'),
('1', '2', 'check ...','2011-08-21 14:13:29'),
('1', '1', 'test2 ...','2011-08-21 14:14:09'),
('2', '1', 'check2 ...','2011-08-21 14:15:09'),
('2', '1', 'test3 ...','2011-08-21 14:16:09'),
('1', '2', 'buzz ...','2011-08-21 14:17:09'),
('1', '2', 'test ...','2011-08-21 14:18:19'),
('1', '2', 'check ...','2011-08-21 14:19:29'),
('1', '1', 'test2 ...','2011-08-21 14:10:09'),
('3', '1', 'check2 ...','2011-08-21 14:21:09'),
('3', '1', 'test3 ...','2011-08-21 14:22:09'),
('3', '2', 'buzz ...','2011-08-21 14:24:09'),
('3', '2', 'test ...','2011-08-21 14:25:19'),
('1', '3', 'check ...','2011-08-21 14:26:29'),
('1', '3', 'test2 ...','2011-08-21 14:27:09'),
('2', '3', 'check2 ...','2011-08-21 14:28:09'),
('2', '3', 'test3 ...','2011-08-21 14:29:09'),
('1', '2', 'check3 ...','2011-08-21 14:23:09');
```

Summarizing:

1.Group all users seperately with all their msgs and count ORDER BY date DESC

For EG:
A new feature is to group these messages like Facebook in one. Let's say:

```
 user A is sending user B a message
 user B is replying to A
 User A is sending user C a Message
 user D is sending user A a message
```

So user A must have three blocks of users : B, C, D.  for the display.
B includes (1,2), C includes (3) and D includes (4), even if C is not replying to A (3) and A not to D (4).

Also on click of each user it will open their messaging history.

Comment: I can't see that. Can you just paste the desired result in your code.

Comment: @Strawberry I have updated more info on top Exactly dont know the format : Something like grouping all messages wrt to particular user in one block.So I will need multiple blocks representing each user and his message history.Thanks again for your time.You can suggest anything and I will check if thats working.Thanks again.

Comment: Until you can tell us what the result set would look like, it's hard for us to help. Also, this messaging system allows a sender to send a message to only one receiver at a time. Is that right?

Comment: looking into it will get back to you quickly .thanks again please look into it in the meantime.Thanks

Comment: @Strawberry Something on these lines http://www.9lessons.info/2013/05/message-conversation-database-design.html  . In my case its only user and conversation.No extra table.